# Managing AWS Secrets Manager in AWS Glue

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-secrets-manager

How can we reliably manage secrets in AWS Glue jobs ?

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
logger = glueContext.get_logger()
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
logger = glueContext.get_logger()
```

Thanks

Comment: `boto3.client("secretsmanager").get_secret_value(SecretId="whatever")`!? What exactly is the question / problem?

Comment: Yeah! that's it

Answer (score 0):

After creating a secret in `aws secrets manager`, it suggests a sample code that we can use to retrieve the secrets

```py
# Use this code snippet in your app.
# If you need more information about configurations or implementing the sample code, visit the AWS docs:   
# https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/python/

import boto3
import base64
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def get_secret():

    secret_name = "myKafkaSecret"
    region_name = "eu-west-3"

    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )

    # In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
    # See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
    # We rethrow the exception by default.

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailureException':
            # Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceErrorException':
            # An error occurred on the server side.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            # You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            # You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            # We can't find the resource that you asked for.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
    else:
        # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
        # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
        else:
            decoded_binary_secret = base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])
            
    # Your code goes here.
```